# Clone arr3----> store the result in a variable arr6 Would this be correct?

Tags: java

Clone arr3----> store the result in a variable arr6

```
static long[] arr6 = (long[])arr3.clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

The above will work if its declared as part of a class variable and arr3 is also of type `long[]`. It will not work if this statement is in a static or instance method. Is there any particular reason your making it static. If not you may want to drop `static`.

You are best off testing it out yourself and making small changes to see what the effect is. That way you will really understand if it works or not.